# Minkowski functional characterization for convex and absorbing sets

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(X,\|\;\|)$ be a normed vector space over $K$. Let $E\subset X$ be convex and absorbing. And let $E_1=\{x\in X:p_E(x)<1\}$, $E_2=\{x\in X: p_E(x)\le 1\}$; where $p_E(x)=\inf_{x\in tE}\{t>0\}$. I want to prove that:
$$
E^\circ\subset E_1\subset E\subset E_2\subset\overline E
$$
I'm stucked figuring out how does every $x\in E^\circ$ should satisfy $p_E(x)<1$. I only got that for every $x\in E^\circ$ I can found $r_x>0$ s.t. $B_{r_x}(x)\subset E^\circ$, but doesn't seem to help. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the second one: $E_1\subset E$

Let $x\in E_1$, then clearly $x\in p_E(x)E$ and
$$
0\le p_E(x)<1
$$
so, since E is convex and absorbing, we get that
$$
p_E(x)E\subseteq 1E=E
$$
thus $x\in E$ and, thereby, $E_1\subset E$

Comment: It is generally not the case that $x \in p_E(x)E$. (Look at the one-dimensional situation to see it clearly.) But for every $s > p_E(x)$ one has $x \in s\cdot E$. Use that.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! Any ideas to prove that if $p_E(x)<s\Rightarrow x\in sE$ ?

Comment: Since $E$ is absorbing, we have $0\in E$. By definition of $p_E$, if $p_E(x) < s$ there is a $0 <t < s$ with $x \in tE$. Write that as $\frac{1}{t}x \in E$. Use the convexity of $E$ to deduce $\frac{1}{s}x \in E$.

Comment: Thanks! Think I got it: so continuing with your idea, since $\frac{t}{s}\in (0,1)$ we get that 
$$
\frac{t}{s}\Big(\frac{1}{t}x\Big) + \Big(1-\frac{t}{s}\Big)0\in E
$$
thus
$$
\frac{1}{s}x\in E
$$

Comment: Right. $E \subset E_2$ is easy, then it remains to show $E_2 \subset \overline{E}$. I suggest you show $E_2 \subset \overline{E}_1$, doing that may make the idea more easy to see.

Comment: Ok, what do you think of this:
Let $x\in E_2$ and let $r>0$. Taking $x_r=\frac{x}{1+r}$ we get that $x_r\in B_r(x)$, since $\|x_r-x\|=\Big|\frac{r}{1+r}\Big|\|x\|<\|x\|<r$ and $p_E(x_r)=\frac{1}{1+r}p_E(x)\le\frac{1}{1+r}<1$. Thus, $\forall r>0\;B_r(x)\cap E_1\neq\emptyset$, thereby $E_2\subset \overline E_1$

Comment: And, since $E_1\subset E$, then $\overline E_1\subset \overline E$ and thus $E_2\subset \overline E$

Comment: Yup, that's good. You should however collect everything in a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to prove this first part ($E^\circ\subset E_1$):
Let $x\in E^\circ$, so there $\exists\;r_0>0$ s.t. $B_{r_0}(x)\subset E^\circ$. Taking $\tilde r_0=\min\{r_0,1\}$ we get that:
$$
\|(1+\tilde r_0)x-x\|=|\tilde r_0|\|x\|\le\|x\|<r_0\;\Rightarrow (1+\tilde r_0)x\in B_{r_0}(x)
$$
and, since $B_{r_0}(x)\subset E^\circ\subset E$, we get that:
$$
(1+\tilde r_0)x\in E\Leftrightarrow x\in \frac{1}{1+\tilde r_0}E
$$
thus
$$
p_E(x)\le\frac{1}{1+\tilde r_0}<1
$$
so $x\in E_1$ and thereby $E^\circ\subset E_1$